# Stuck using onClick opening Dialog box

Tags: jquery

Very new to this and am stuck already with an onClick command and it's puzzling me.

What's meant to happen:
User clicks on the Shopping Cart text (within a div element which has been styled) and it opens a dialog box containing the users cart contents.

Here's the code below...

I think I've done a tad to much this week as I'm probably missing something really easy and am just being stupid.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Copy code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$( 'div.dialog' ).dialog( {modal:true,autoOpen:false} );
$('CartLink').on( 'click', function() {
    var index = $(this).index() + 1;
    $( '#dialog' +  index ).dialog( 'open' );
});
});
</script>

    <div class="dialog" id="dialog1">Shopping Cart Contents</div>

<div id="CartLink" class="fluid ShoppingCart"><img src="images/Site/Shopping_cart.gif"         
alt="" width="25" height="23"/>Shopping Cart</div>
```

Comment: what is CartLink? If it is an ID then use #, if a class - use a dot '.'

Comment: Ahh thank you everyone for your very quick replies! Much much appreciated :) I have tried to update this as suggested but the dialog box still does not open :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seem like you're missing `#` to target `id` here

```
$('#CartLink').on( 'click', function() {
//-^ here -----
    var index = $(this).index() + 1;
    $( '#dialog' +  index ).dialog( 'open' );
});
```

---

You need to change:

```
var index = $(this).index() + 1;
```

to:

```
var index = $(this).index();
```

because currently the `index` of your `#CartLink` is `1` not `0` as what you're expected. So you don't need to increase it by `1` anymore.

Comment: Ahh thank you everyone for your very quick replies! Much much appreciated :) I have tried to update this as suggested but the dialog box still does not open :(

Comment: No errors, No page loading issues.  The Dialog box loads when I set the autoOpen: true so that appears correctly as it should also.  I am stumped

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This is now working.  I was going to use the script to call 2 different dialog boxes, which is why the +1 was indexed, but I can just use an additional script.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing `#` before the [**`id` selector**](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

```
$(function() {
    $( 'div.dialog' ).dialog( {modal:true,autoOpen:false} );
    $('#CartLink').on( 'click', function() {
    //.^.....add # here.......
        var index = $(this).index();
        $( '#dialog' +  index ).dialog( 'open' );
    });
});
```

Comment: Ahh thank you everyone for your very quick replies!  Much much appreciated :)

I have tried to update this as suggested but the dialog box still does not open :(

Answer (score 0):

Do not rely on `.index()` to link your dialog(s) to your button(s). The example you asked worked because *currently*, `div#CartLink` is the second child in its parent node, but any modification in your html (adding a title in your div, having to move the button to another part of the screen, etc ...) will break this asumption.

One simple way is to put the target dialog id explicitly in a custom attribute :

```
<div id="dialog1">...</div>
<div id="CartLink" data-dialog="dialog1" class="...">...</div>


$('#CartLink').on('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-dialog');
    $('#'+id).dialog('open');
});
```